# CMOS pulse-width converter

Tags: analog, integrated-circuit, cmos

I'm trying to build a circuit that output an analog voltage proportional to the duration of a voltage pulse at the input like this:

[image]

My idea is to charge a capacitor with a current mirror with a switch controlled by the input pulse.

I have build this circuit so far.

[image]

But it has some issues that I would like you to help me with. Here is the output that I got:

[image]

First, I need it to start at 0V but it currently starts at 1.7V. I was thinking about shorting it to the ground when my input is at 0V but I don't know how to do it.
Also I would like to control the slope because at this point, it is way too big and it even stops at 2.7V, I think it is because the transistors is not in saturation anymore.

Do you have any advice?

Thank you

---

So I managed to have a lower slope by increasing the capacitor to 5pF (max allowed values) and also by decreasing the current from the current mirror. Such that my slope stays linear even for impulse of width 250 ns (max values).

Also I got rid of the offset by adding a switch and an inverter like this:

[image]

Here is what I got as output:

[image]

Which is already better because it enables the circuit to work for successive pulses, as Vout is reset between pulses.

But the main issue is that I wanted to keep my output voltage constant once my first pulse is done and only reset it on the rising edge of the second pulse. And by adding the switch with M6, I don't have the holding principle anymore.

Anyone with an idea to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: The load pF and parasitic pF needs to exceed 1pF . What is the Cin and parasitic pF of the buffer for this signal ? The FET Coss must be minimized relative to the load. The offset voltage , I have to think about. For dV/dt=1V/10ns=Ic/C you have some other choices on transparent switches.  The effective -3dB BW =0.35 / 8ns= 44MHz but for -0.? dB error BW is perhaps 10x more !

Comment: The circuit you need is an integrator. The voltage on the capacitor is an integral of the current through it. You are on the right path. In order to start the integration at 0v you need to short the capacitor to ground when the input signal is low - you can do that with an inverter and an nmos connected to the capacitor. As for the slope, is proportional to the current so you need to reduce the current to reduce the slope.

Comment: 1 pF is too small, rather than reduce current, increase load C

Comment: What is the minimum rep rate for Int. & Hold? then rezero time error?  i.e. what dV/dt and then dt or dV error for rezero is acceptable?

Comment: By the "CMOS" in the question title I assume that this maybe homework for a VLSI course, and thus the transistors capacitances are probably much much lower than 1 pF.

Comment: For the slope, it shouldn't exceed 3.3V before 250 ns. But I also would like to control that slope with another input signal. So I was thinking about using a transistor as a resistor instead of R2. Such that I could control the current of the current mirror.

For the capacitor, it  is max 5 pF. I don't have any value of parasitic, neither rezero time error. We can assume it to be ignored.

@TonyStewartEE75

Comment: For ALL rep. rates there MUST be a maximum duty cycle and therefore and mandatory rezero time necessary for the integrator. Or is it a one-shot PW50 measurement? and hold then how long is the HOLD time and thus sag allowed.  Then what is your resolution tolerance and minimum PW50?

Comment: The pulse width should be between 5 ns to 250 ns but I'm not sure I understand your point.
At first I would like to be able to measure a single pulse and holding the output. Then as next more advanced stage, I want to measurement consecutive pulse which means that when input is in the rising edge, the output should be reset to 0V.

Comment: For now, I'm able to measure a single pulse but I have an offset of 1.66 V. So I was thinking about adding a branch with Vin and an inverter connected to a switch (M 6) with source grounded. Such that when input is high M3 is passing current and switch M6 is open, but when output is low, M3 is open but M6 is close such that Vout is grounded.
But the think is that if I do that, I would not be holding my output anymore once the input pulse is no longer high.

Comment: Normally I would rely on a $10k HP Time Interval Counter instrument to perform 5ns pulse widths with picosecond rise times. You seem to be ignoring the microwave aspects of this design. It must be 50 Ohm logic levels in CML differential mode to control the integration.  **Anything less will be hopeless.**  I used this instr. on HPIB to measure Phase modulation of a UHF carrier to GOES sat 1 on this order of magnitude successfully.  AS you redefine your design specs in the question  (V, Z, Tr, PW50, f C , tolerance errors etc  ,**you might have some chance of getting to an acceptable solution**

Comment: I'm a student and I'm doing this only on a simulation tool (LTspice) where I can neglect a lot of things. I don't plan on building this circuit.
Which means that I don't bother with all those complicate stuff and I'm more focus on the "logic" of the implementation. Like how to get rid off that offset at the output.

Comment: You have to use Rail to Rail op amp for getting rid of that offset. For example TLC2272. You may use counter and R2R ladder DAC.

Comment: THen for logic reduce pulse width requirements by 3 orders of magnitude to allow for reset time and bandwidth of simple integrate and hold then dump to work. Otherwise modify @Michal 's cct with a /2 FF and instead of integrate and reset, do integrate and hold then read voltage and toggle to 2nd circuit for next pulse integrate  and hold then dump the 1st. Using dual circuits , every second pulse has time to reset while 1st is integrating.    Then vary the current gain with a bilateral CMOS switch to his R1 to change currents.  You don't have experience to do 5 ns pulse widths accurately yet.

Comment: As you say that you want to reset the capacitor on the rising edge of the pulse - replace the inverter with an edge detector. And beef up M6 to have a faster reset.

Answer (score 1):

Blue is pulsed input signal, green is Cap voltage.

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

Regarding to one pulse only reset the 2pF Cap imediately after input pulse go low is undesirable so disconnect the Cap rather and reset is before next measurement only. For holding the voltage for longer time buffer it to bigger Cap. You can disconnect the bigger one after input signal goes low (+ charging time of big one) so it isnt affect by discharging the small one.

[image]

Comment: Now try it for 10ns to 100 ns instead of 10 us !!! And have  a hold after integration.

Comment: It was just to show principle.

Comment: He already has an Integrate and hold principle.

Comment: Thanks it looks great. Could you explain why the first slope is not like the others?
Because the input signal is not supposed to be periodic, so only having the good slope after the first cycle might be an issue.
@MichalPodmanický

Also I should use 3.3 V as supply voltage and MOSFET transistors. Would it make any trouble?

Comment: @Saens  The first slope is distored by initial Vrise of power supply in simulator. 3v3 using right Mosfets should be ok. If you are interested about just one period, maybe the shorting is necessary before mesurement only (to reset Cap). It depends on your aplication. You can disconnect the programing 10k leg to stop charging the Cap.

Comment: @Saens Regarding the 3v3 you must count with about 1V (maybe lower) drop on high-side P-channels. So the maximum Cap voltage will be about 2V3. Try to find some low Vgs Fets available.

Comment: I don't understand what are doing Q4 and Q5. Because on your design, you don't have the offset at the output (I have 1.66V) and I wan't to get rid off it. Do you use them as switch like I did with M3?
Because I feel like I can't have both the "hold" and no offset. My goal is to be able to have sucessive pulse that hold their value until the next pulse arrives (where the output is reset and start increasing linearly again)

Comment: Q4 is an inverter and Q5 again inverts and discharges the Cap when Vin=0 but there is no "hold mechanism" which could be opening R1 from gnd with multiple R switches or a VCCS . The cap would have to be buffered by JFET or low Cin Op Amp to ADC then Q5 could be triggered when done for the Tmin period like 2 Ohms * 1nF = 2 ns for 64% so extended to 10T for 0V decay.

Comment: @Saens  Q4 and Q5 are in switching state (saturated) making logic for reseting, direct (one transistor) reseting would short Cap when input is high and you probably dont want this behavior. In analog systems is hard to "store" voltage for long time, with 5pF it is even harder. With such low capacity you must use high input Z op-amp and quickly buffer voltage to some another higher C Cap.